# How do I store data in arrays from input file?

Tags: c++

I am asked to write a program that grades students' answers to multiple-choice questions. The key and the students’ answers are stored in a file.

In the input file, there are repetitions of the following: 
A name in a line followed by 15 answers, one per line (1 A, 2 D etc.)

I don't know how to store input data in two separate arrays: Key[14] and StudentAnswers[14]. For example, if the name is "Key", the following 15 lines are supposed to be stored into Key[14] array, and StudentAnswers[14] if otherwise.

The following is mainline, and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>  

int main()
{

const int MAX = 15;
std::ifstream   InputFile; 
std::string     Name; 
int             QuestionNumber;
char            Answer;
char            Key[MAX];
char            StudentAnswer[MAX];
char            Mark[MAX];   

while (! InputFile.eof())
{

std::getline(InputFile, Name); 
std::cout << Name << "\n"; 

if (Name == "zzz")
break;        //  Read answers wether key or students' answers    

for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) 

{
//  If the name is key, store these in Key array 
//  else store them in StudentAnswer array 

InputFile >> QuestionNumber >> Answer;
std::cout << QuestionNumber << "  " << Answer << "\n";   
}

//  If the name is not key, then grade it 
//  To grade it, go thru whole array compare Key[i] w/ StudentAnswer[i]
//      if same set Mark[i] = ' '
//      else set Mark[i] = 'X'; 
//  Print result 

}

std::string Junk;
std::getline(InputFile, Junk); 
}

InputFile.close(); 
OutputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: ignore software for a minute ... think about the problem and conceptualize what needs to get done and zero in on an approach ... code up that attempt, test and tweak ...  feel free to fail ... throw out that approach when you invent a new approach while brushing your teeth

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!